# How to convert string date to notification date format in Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, datetime, notifications, ionic2

Im trying to use my string date in my notification function but I don't know how can I convert string to be used in the notification.

For example:

my string date = 2017-11-03, 16:38

SO, Is possible to convert it to be supported in notification function?

> **Note:** I installed moment.js but I don't know how can I use it to convert my string date

Edit:

Here is my notification function with worked date

```
addNotification() {
    let date=  new Date(new Date().getTime() + 5 * 1000);
    alert("Your notification will be shown at " + date);
    this.localNotifications.schedule({
        id: 1,
        title: "Test Title",
        text: "Delayed Notification",
        at: date,
        //every: 'week'
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you share your notification function please ?

Comment: @Antikhippe now u can see my notification funcation with worked date

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can easily use *Moment.js* to convert your string date :

```
sDate = "2017-11-03, 16:38";
mDate = moment(sDate, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
```

See it in action in [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YHdwtGsYbj9VQictEmwS?p=preview)